# Dogs and their role: how to accept that I may not be able to use my dog as emotional support?

Tags: dogs, health

As-salamu alaikum

I have been contemplating reverting to islam for the last couple of months. It is not something I take lightly by any means. There are still however certain things in which I feel deep within my bones must have exceptions one of which is the use of dogs.

Now I am not a huge animal person in general (growing up animals were only allowed in certain parts of the house) I do however struggle with extreme mental health issues that I have sought out treatment for the last 7 years or so ( extensive therapy, various medications and other treatments. It is to the point I would call it a disability) although thy seemed to help some nothing has helped as much as my puppy that I got about 5 months ago. I was struggling to the worst degree I have ever struggled truly wanting to die, not getting out of bed or taking care of myself drinking in excess, complete despair until I got my little lab and I feel like Allah sent her to me. She has helped me get out of bed nearly every morning (maybe 5 mornings total in the past 5 and a half months where I couldn't get up to take care of her) as well as stay out of bed as she needs attention, she has forced me to go on walks talk to others and motivated me to continue treatment and quit drinking. She has the best temperament of a puppy I have ever met and has helped me through panic attacks and calmed me down so I wouldnt harm myself. I never thought an animal could so drastically change my quality of life but she has. I now live on my own work part time and am getting my life back together after the last 10 months of pain and bad circumstances. As a woman it is also comforting to know I have a dog around and she deters the wildlife around. My point is she is the main reason I have gained so much progress and peace. Why would God/Allah allow so much help to come from a puppy when they are haram? I can honestly say I would not be able to function without her, I am working on training her to help with my panic attacks even more by notifying me of my breathing and doing deep pressure therapy. She is the best least mouthy and good listener for a puppy I have ever met and many people agree that she has an unusually good temperament. I am very allergic to cats so I know that would not be a solution and for the first time in my life I feel independent and capable largely due to her help. She is technically a hunting breed, but I do not hunt and I am not looking for a loophole like training her to hunt just to keep her after she has done so much for me as Allah knows our intensions. But why would he bring her to me if I am not supposed to keep her in my home? How will other muslims understand that she is more like a service dog than a pet? Will I be accepted if I am not strong enough to change things(because quite frankly she keeps me healthy and alive)?
wa’l-salaamu ‘alaykum

Comment: I think first you should verify whether it is indeed considered haram for a person with emotional support needs to keep a dog when there are no alternatives. (Most scholars I know would say it is not haram.)

Comment: Where did you hear that owning a puppy is haram ? It's not haram, obviously not. Also, why is your mental health really bad ? I can help you if you want.